# Using Windows as middle for migrating between two Linux machines

Tags: linux, scripting, migration

We're developing a tool that will do a migration between some platforms. Both source and/or destination servers can be Windows or Linux.

The tool is currently built in .NET and we'd like to keep it that way if possible. But a new requirement emerged that requires us to copy files and their permissions.

So my questions are

- Is it possible to copy permissions (or read old then write file and set new permissions)?
- Possibly related, is it possible to execute remote scripts from windows (say PowerShell) on Linux?

Is this possible, and where can I find any documentation on this topic?

Comment: If you don't need to modify the data, you could tar it using -pcvzf flag and -pxvzf to untar it. Then you preseve all permissions.

Comment: @Aragon0 cool but can I execute a command to tar files from windows server on linux?

Comment: Yes, mount it using ftp or samba

Comment: @FedorHajdu If you just need to execute the command manually, [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) will allow you to login to the CLI (via SSH) of the Linux server. You can also try installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html), which would allow you to SSH into the Linux server, and execute the tar command.

Comment: Not manually, I'm writing a migration application so I need to execute commands on source and destination servers, but everything must be automatic and done on a third server.